# how to resolve this error: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'height'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, typeerror

I want to make a graph order frequency of each city. For this, I am trying to pass cities name on x-axis and their number on y-axis. I keep facing this error  `TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'height'` . Here is the code:

```
order_status = df.Order_Status.value_counts()

#making separate column for unique cities 
unique_city = df.City.value_counts()

plt.bar(x=unique_city.index, y=unique_city.values)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Replace `y` with `height` https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
unique_city.plot.bar()
```

Or like @ commented:

> Replace `y` with `height` matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html